# Hibernate, Null values and nativeSQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate with mySQL and I've the following problem: I do a **nativeSQL** query on a table with, among others, a column that is a character long. This column can get to null. Now I receive the following exception while querying:

```
4-feb-2010 10.31.00 org.hibernate.type.NullableType nullSafeGet
INFO: could not read column value from result set: nazeuro; String index out of range: 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
        at org.hibernate.type.CharacterType.get(CharacterType.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(CustomLoader.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(CustomLoader.java:420)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
        at Views.Components.QuickLookup$updater.run(QuickLookup.java:102)
```

I've been googling to solve the issue, I even found posts here on SO, but everytime it is about mapping to objects and writing custom classes to handle the issue. In this situation what I need is a Object array. I know a solution could be to change the table but I'd avoid it as I've to work with a pre-existing db. So do you have any possible solutions?

---

```
SQLQuery query = sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * from " + table + " WHERE " + filter + " LIKE '" + search + "%'");
                    System.out.println(query.toString());
                    List<Object[]> result = query.list();
```

Comment: So the column is a `CHAR(1)`? And what is the type in your entity? Please show your code.

Comment: There is no type in my entity, in fact it is a NATIVE SQL QUERY, that will return an Object[] per row (one object per column). So there is no entity...

Comment: We need to see your code especially the Hibernate mapping

Comment: I TELL AGAIN THERE IS NO MAPPING AS THIS IS NATIVE SQL QUERY THAT RETURNS AN OBJECT ARRAY JUST AS A JDBC ONE!

Comment: thanks for shouting. good luck finding it :P

(P.S. GIVE THE CODE that causes this stacktrace) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Hibernate version are you using? In 3.3.2, this is `CharacterType.get()`:

```
public Object get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws SQLException {
    String str = rs.getString(name);
    if (str==null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return new Character( str.charAt(0) );
    }
}
```

In case this wasn't obvious, the exception indicates that you got an empty, non-null string (`""`) from the result set, which causes `CharacterType` to barf, as this is not an expected value for a `CHAR(1)`. (This is a `CHAR(1)` column, is it?)

Comment: I'm using 3.2.5 . I think I should get a JDBC connection and bypass hibernate... do you have better ideas?

Comment: @Gotch: That's definitely an option, you're not using any of its features at this point anyway except HQL. 

I'd be curious though how an empty string can make it into the result set. If you query the CHAR column manually with `WHERE charCol = ''`, do you get a result? If so, maybe the JDBC driver is at fault, who knows.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use native function LEFT or RIGHT to change the column datatype in origin

let's suppose this was the SQL query giving the error select username from Users

change it with: select **LEFT**(username,**100**) from Users

the number should be equal to the size of the field

Answer (score 0):

Use the CASE expression for every character column in your table

CASE column_name = '' THEN ' ' ELSE column_name END